# Downloading dataset from SRA (SOLiD Platform)

Tags: ngs

Trying to download colorspace data from SRA, but getting an error

`abi-dump -A SRR1657115.sra`

abi-dump.2.9.6 err: item not found while constructing within virtual database module - the path 'SRR1657115.sra' cannot be opened as database or table.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the accession name without the `.sra` suffix.

`abi-dump -A SRR1657115`